# NSBundle instance method URLForResource:withExtension returning invalid CFStringRef on device

Tags: ios, xcode, nsbundle

I make the following method call in my code:

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"myappname" withExtension:@"momd"];
```

When I run on the simulator, this returns an NSURL that works. When I run on my device, it returns an invalid CFStringRef. What am I doing wrong?

Another related question, my xcode project file is named like this: "MyApp",
and the end of my bundle identifier is named like this: "myapp".

I have tried both ways and I get the same result, but I've read that the resource parameter string is case sensitive. Which one am I supposed to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
NSString *modelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YourModelName" ofType:@"momd"];
NSManagedObjectModel *objectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:modelPath]];
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I realized that I need to use the name of my model, which was written like this: "Myapp". I think that probably on the simulator the name is not case sensitive and on the device it is.